# Storing DateTime values individual

Tags: c#, datetime, devexpress, datetime-format

I have two variables one is for date and the other for time and I want to store their values (date+time) to one variables which type is `DateTime` .

```
DateTime x;
x = timeEdit1.Time;      // return datetime as current time and current date
x = dateEdit2.DateTime;  // return datetime as current date and '12:00:00 AM'
```

Comment: Specifying what exactly is the problem would help people help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the appropriate properties of `DateTime`: [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
TimeSpan time = timeEdit1.Time.TimeOfDay;
DateTime date = dateEdit2.Date;
```

If you want to store them in one `DateTime`:

```
DateTime dateAndTime = dateEdit2.Date + timeEdit1.Time.TimeOfDay;
```

Now you have both in one, you can extract them as shown in my first snippet.

Comment: yes , but I cant store them in DateTime as one value

Comment: @abdullahRasheed: then add both and extract them as shown above, i've edited it. As an aside, you should make `timeEdit1.Time` a `TimeSpan` instead of a `DateTime`.

Comment: I get error msg : Operator '+' cannot be applied to operand type(    TimeSpan + DateTime

Comment: @abdullahRasheed: You need to the the `TimeSpan` to the `DateTime` in the sequence Tim has shown: `DateTime` + `TimeSpan`.

Comment: @abdullahRasheed: i assume that you have used `timeEdit1.Time` instead of `timeEdit1.Time.TimeOfDay`. I've edited my answer directly after i've posted it. That's why i've commmented that you should use `TimeSpan` in the first place.

Comment: @abdullahRasheed: "two method" means "both methods"? If so, which both? Is `timeEdit1.Time` a `DateTime` where the date is irrelevant and `dateEdit2` a `DateTime` where the time is irrelevant? Then `dateEdit2.Date + timeEdit1.Time.TimeOfDay` should give you a `DateTime` which unions both and you get the date with the `Date` property and the time with the `TimeOfDay` property.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter : I try store     "timeEdit1.Time.TimeOfDay" then add it with date and success . Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the date and time in the initialization phase:

```
DateTime x = new DateTime(dateEdit2.Date.Year, dateEdit2.Date.Month, dateEdit2.Date.Day, timeEdit1.TimeOfDay.Hours, timeEdit2.TimeOfDay.Minutes, timeEdit2.TimeOfDay.Seconds);
```

To get the value and show it into MessageBox you can simply do:

```
MessageBox.Show(x.Date.ToString() + " " + x.TimeOfDay.ToSTring());
```